Can't get unwrapped coordinate bounds in MapBox on Android for multiple visible earths
Depending on screen ratio, when you zoom out in mapbox for Android, you can see multiple copies of the earth.
The longitude bounds of a single map are -180 to 180. When I zoom out as shown in the picture below, I should receive visible bounds of around -240 to -240, but for both wrapped and unwrapped bounds, I get -121 to 116.
wide world map
 val options =
            CameraOptions.Builder().zoom(mapboxMap.cameraState.zoom)
                .center(mapboxMap.cameraState.center)
                .bearing(mapboxMap.cameraState.bearing)
                .pitch(mapboxMap.cameraState.pitch)
                .build()

val unwrappedBounds = mapboxMap.coordinateBoundsForCameraUnwrapped(options)
val wrappedBounds = mapboxMap.coordinateBoundsForCamera(options)

println("Wrapped: $wrappedBounds")
println("Unwrapped: $unwrappedBounds")

I expected to get bounds that exceeded -180 to 180, but the unwrapped results seem to be wrapping.
LOG RESULTS:
 Wrapped: [southwest: Point{type=Point, bbox=null, 
coordinates=[-121.1356988416266,-82.59314961488414]}, northeast: Point{type=Point, bbox=null, 
coordinates=[116.56624773466814, 82.94613012791345]}, infiniteBounds: false]

 Unwrapped: [southwest: Point{type=Point, bbox=null, 
coordinates=[-121.1356988416266, -82.59314961488414]}, northeast: Point{type=Point, bbox=null, 
coordinates=[116.56624773466814, 82.94613012791345]}, infiniteBounds: false]


It turns out this was a bug with Mapbox 11.0.0. I updated to 11.6.0 and the issue was resolved.

It turns out this was a bug with Mapbox 11.0.0. I updated to 11.6.0 and the issue was resolved.
